# unable to install R packages - unknown input format

Tags: r

I have a work laptop that has recently forced a migration to microsoft OneDrive and all kinds of things have been squirrely since then, so I'll preface that MAYBE that has something to do with it.  I'm running R 3.6.3 in RStudio.

Suddenly today though when I try to install a package I get a very weird error message I've never encountered before

```
install.packages("tidyquant")
warning in install.packages  :
   unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
   Found continuation line starting ' <!DOCTYPE html> ...' at begin of record.
   Error in install.packages  :  unknown input format
```

I tried some troubleshooting steps found elsewhere including

- uncheck the global option for require secure download
- delete the .Rhistory file and run `update.packages()`

when I run `update.packages()` I get

```
Error in readRDS(dest)  :  unknown input format
```

Any advice on how to proceed would be most appreciated.

Comment: The message "unable to access index for repository" sounds like your computer can't connect to CRAN to download the package. Perhaps your work laptop has been configured to not allow that traffic. It's also possible that there was some other temporary network disruption. Can you access that URL in your browser?

Comment: Ahhh...so it seems our IT goons have gotten even more intrusive.  Used to be you could download files when you were on your home internet and not behind the work firewall.  But now...I can go to http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib and I get an index.  But if I manually download tidyquant (which is a 3.5 MB tar.gz file) I get a 2kb file.  It still has the .tar.gz extension, but if you open it with notepad it's an html doc with lots of references to menlosecurity download monitor.  BAH!